# Rename [lunar-module] to [apollo-lunar-module]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

While a viable lunar mission might be some years off still, I've noted that the existing [lunar-module](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar-module) tag is geared towards Apollo exclusively.

> The Lunar Module was part of the Apollo program spacecraft package. It rode into orbit beneath the Command Module and required extraction once there. It consisted of a descent stage (which remained on the Moon after landing) and an ascent stage (to take astronauts back into orbit). Use with the [apollo-program] tag any any appropriate mission tags.

Since everything seems [apollo-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apollo-program) related, a simple rename to [apollo-lunar-module] would help us differentiate questions about this pioneering spacecraft from those about upcoming lunar modules/landers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is really necessary since "Lunar Module" is a pretty well understood name here, and any future spacecraft used for that purpose will probably have different names. If it does become an issue, we can always make a change at that point, but I don't think there's a need to do anything preemptively.

Comment: For a generic lunar lander there is already [lander].